# Button is automatically touched in reusable table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a button in my custom cell of tableview. The button is automatically in pressed state (i have checked it from isTouchInside) whenever i scroll the table view.  I have used reuseable cell. How can i fix this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bookTimeCellView", for: indexPath) as! BookTimeCellView
        print("Button state : \(cell.bookButton.isTouchInside)")
        cell.timeLabel.text = timeArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
}
```

This is the image of my custom cell
[Custom View Cell Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XapSK.png)

Whenever i click on booknow button and scroll then other button in cell is also in pressed state.

This is the custom class that i used for button
**UIButtonX**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class UIButtonX: UIButton {

    enum FromDirection:Int {
        case Top = 0
        case Right = 1
        case Bottom = 2
        case Left = 3
    }

    var shadowView: UIView!
    var direction: FromDirection = .Left
    var alphaBefore: CGFloat = 1

    @IBInspectable var animate: Bool = false
    @IBInspectable var animateDelay: Double = 0.2
    @IBInspectable var animateFrom: Int {
        get {
            return direction.rawValue
        }
        set (directionIndex) {
            direction = FromDirection(rawValue: directionIndex) ?? .Left
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var popIn: Bool = false
    @IBInspectable var popInDelay: Double = 0.4

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        self.clipsToBounds = true

        if animate {
            let originalFrame = frame

            if direction == .Bottom {
                frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y + 200, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
            }

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: animateDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                self.frame = originalFrame
            }, completion: nil)
        }

        if popIn {
            transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: popInDelay, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }, completion: nil)
        }

        if shadowView == nil && shadowOpacity > 0 {
            shadowView = UIView(frame: self.frame)
            shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            shadowView.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
            shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius).cgPath
            shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
            shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = Float(shadowOpacity)
            shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
            shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            shadowView.clipsToBounds = false

            self.superview?.addSubview(shadowView)
            self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
        }
    }

    override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        alphaBefore = alpha

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.4
        })

        return true
    }

    override func endTracking(_ touch: UITouch?, with event: UIEvent?) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.alpha = self.alphaBefore
        })
    }

    // MARK: - Borders

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
            layer.masksToBounds = cornerRadius > 0
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Shadow

    @IBInspectable public var shadowOpacity: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable public var shadowColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear
    @IBInspectable public var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0
    @IBInspectable public var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)


   //    MARK: - Gradient
    @IBInspectable var firstColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var secondColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var horizontalGradient: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    override public class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get {
            return CAGradientLayer.self
        }
    }

    func updateView() {
        let layer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
        layer.colors = [ firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor ]

        if (horizontalGradient) {
            layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
            layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        } else {
            layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Add your code what you have done so far. So that we can help you out :)

Comment: @AmirKhan i have added the image of my cell and some code. please help me out ;)

Comment: Check your `Cell's Xib`, whether you made any default state to that button.

Comment: @AmirKhan It is in default state.

Comment: You mean to say whenever you scroll the `Table` Button's `target` method is being Called? is it?

Comment: Can you add your `cellForRowAt` code snippet, where you add target to cell's button ?

Comment: Only Button UI is changed to Pressed state. I checked if the button was actually pressed then it wasn't. It just change the Button UI  and the touchInside was true but the target method was not called until i press the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `prepareForReuse` of `UITableViewCell`, this is where you revert any UI controls before being reused, like so:

```
class BookTimeCellView: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var button = CustomButton()

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        // normally following are the button states you would reset
        self.button.isSelected = false
        self.button.isHighlighted = false

        // This seems some CustomButton property
        self.bookButton.isTouchInside = false
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not in the selected state. It is in pressed state which i checked with isTouchInside.

Comment: Please post the code how you checked it on the first place, or just replace the line `self.button.isSelected = false` to make it unchecked

Comment: I have checked the state with this line. `print("Button state : \(cell.bookButton.isTouchInside)")` . This line prints true. If i checked it for other like isHighlighted, isSelected, etc then it prints false. I have already check with self.button.isSelected = false and it didnt work

Comment: I think this will work if the isTouchInside property was both get and set.. But unfortunately this property is get only so we cant set the value

Comment: i have not set the value for `isTouchInside`. I just checked in which state the button was whenever i scroll the tableview. At first all the button was in default state and whenever i press one button in one cell and scroll and it began to change another button state to pressed state. I checked the button state and it only returns true when i check for isTouchInside

Comment: Question updated and i have used the custom class for button that i posted above.